# Amazon SQS Java SDK - cannot receive message attributes

Tags: java, amazon-sqs

After posting a message with an attribute to SQS with the following code before sending it (and checking in SQS console to see if everything is posted correctly)...

```
messageRequest.addMessageAttributesEntry(
        "attributeTest", 
        new MessageAttributeValue()
            .withDataType("String")
            .withStringValue("attributeTest 123"));
```

I cannot retrieve any of the message attributes in the message. All I see, as a result, is "0 attributes.". Reinspecting the message in Amazon SQS console, the message - and the attribute - are still there.

```
// Message was previously checked in SQS console and contains 
// an attribute named "attributeTest"

AmazonSQS sqs = ...
List<Message> messages = sqs.receiveMessage(receiveMessageRequest).getMessages();
for (Message : messages) 
{
    Map<String, MessageAttributeValue> attributes = message.getMessageAttributes();
    System.out.println("" + attributes.size() + " attributes.");
}
```

I am using Amazon SQS SDK v1.8 in Java 1.7 with Play Framework 2.2.3. At first I thought it could be the SQS version but tried upgrading to 1.8.7 with no avail.

The official documentation found [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/SQSMessageAttributes.html) does not provide any sourcecode to read the attributes at all. Nor github searches, stack overflow. I've been trying for a few hours without any success.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You have to specify which message attributes you want in your request (or use "All" to get all message attributes). So in your case you could use either

```
List<Message> messages = sqs.receiveMessage(receiveMessageRequest.withMessageAttributeNames("attributeTest")).getMessages();
```

or

```
List<Message> messages = sqs.receiveMessage(receiveMessageRequest.withMessageAttributeNames("All")).getMessages();
```

If you want the standard attributes (ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp, ApproximateReceiveCount, SenderId, and SentTimestamp) along with your messages, use `withAttributeNames("All")`. You can find more detail in the Javadocs for [ReceiveMessageRequest](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sqs/model/ReceiveMessageRequest.html).

Comment: Worked for me too, once I noticed the difference between ".withAttributeNames()" and ".withMessageAttributeNames()".  Attention to detail is required here.  Doh!

Comment: Great answer, but I still don't know how to receive the custom headers :(

Answer (score 2):

There are two different methods:

- `messageAttributeNames()` which gets custom attributes send with the message,
- `attributeNames()` which gets system attributes linked to the message (`retryCount`, ...)